# two y axis with same scale

Tags: python, matplotlib

I did a histogram with two y-axis and two datasets but I can't set the scales of the two y-axis to the same limits.

In this example http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html#api-two-scales the idea would be to have both scales from 0 to 25.000.

Does anybody have an idea for this case?

Comment: Did you try `ax2.set_ylim(0,25000)`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried something like:

```
...

# twinx to duplicate y axis
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

# set the same limits for both axis
a,b = 0,25000
ax1.set_ylim(a,b)
ax2.set_ylim(a,b)
```

Comment: `ax2.set_ylim(ax1.set_ylim))` aligns ax2 y-scale on ax1. Useful in many cases (i.e. when ax2 scale is already correct).